# ImportError: No module named cloudstorage in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am running my application on Google Cloud and wish to use Google Cloud Storage but getting import error even though my application is live on Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python 2:**

Did you download it into you `lib` folder? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib>
```

Are you vendor-ing in this `lib` folder?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

**Python 3:**

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage

Comment: i got the error: ImportError: No module named setuptools